# Akka version upgrade

Tags: java, akka, akka-actor

I've four java projects (web servers) that communicate with each other using Akka actors.
My question is: What is the side effect of upgrading Akka version in one of the projects from 2.1.2 to the latest version ??

Comment: Have you tried testing it? I guess your question is more about potential incompatibilities.

Comment: How are they communicating? Are they using plain Akka Remoting, or do they form an Akka Cluster, or do they communicate over some API such as Akka HTTP?